# get a element in child element using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add class to the anchors that are `div#mydiv > div > div > anchor` using jquery

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="#aa">add css to this one</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#bb">ignore this one</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Come on... this isn't instant coding service, man!

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
$('#mydiv > div > div > a').addClass('yourClass');
```

Or:

```
$('#mydiv').children('div').children('div').children('a').addClass('yourClass');
```

If you know the `href` beforehand:

```
$('a[href="#aa"]').addClass('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery understand normal CSS rules so you can use

```
$('#mydiv > div > div > a').addClass('someclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mydiv div div a').addClass('someClass');
```

Demo `------->` http://jsfiddle.net/Uq2ap/12/